# Redux toolkit reducer return method doesnt work with object bind

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to use the Redux toolkit reducer with return method but it doesn't work with the object. Am I doing something wrong?

```
const initialState ={
    cartItems :cartItems,
    amount:4,
    total:0,
    isLoading:true
}

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name:"cart",
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        clearCart:(state) =>{
            //state.cartItems =[];
            return {cartItems:[], ...initialState}
        },
        removeItem:(state,action)=>{
            console.log(action)
        }
    }
})
```

This code block works

```
state.cartItems =[];
```

however, this fails

```
return {cartItems:[], ...initialState}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
return {...initialState, cartItems:[]}
```

### Explanation

Order matters:

```js
const a = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3
}
const b = {
  x: 10
}

console.log('a then b', { ...a,
  ...b
})
console.log('b then a', { ...b,
  ...a
})
```

In the above example when the `{ ...a, ...b }` is used this happens:

1. A new empty object is created - `{}`
2. Every property of `a` is added to the new object - `{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }`
3. Every property of 'b' is added to the object - `{ x: 10, y: 2, z: 3 }`

When `{ ...b, ...a }` runs:

1. A new empty object is created - `{}`
2. Every property of `a` is added to the new object - `{ x: 10 }`
3. Every property of `b` is added to the object - `{ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }`

As you can see in the second example `x: 10` is overwritten by `x: 1`

Comment: Czesc Konrad! A few words of explanation why order matters would make this answer much better!